# How to clear text file in Android-java

Tags: java, android, text-files

I have text file in Android called "longlat.txt".

The text file contain latitude and longitude.

I save all the latitude and longitude to the text file using buffreader method.

After I finished using this app, I want to exit the app.
Means that I need to clear "longlat.txt" so that later on when I use the app, it will start the app without previous data that already being save to "longlat.txt".

So I provide a button called "Clear data" to clear the text file.

Now I need some ideas to clear "longlat.txt" file when user click "Clear data" button.

The only method that I'd used to clear the text file is I need to uninstall the app from my phone and reinstall it again .

**I have tried :**

```
public void Clear(View view){    

     PrintWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter("longlat.txt");
         writer.print("");
         writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


     }
```

After I clicked it, I want to check whether the text file already clear or not with click "Update" button, but when I click "Update" button, it still shows the old text file.

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what you've done to try and solve the problem; it currently reads like a request for code. Please share your attempted implementation and explain how it fails to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

When you are closing the program (or any time you want to clear the file), you can simply just write empty data to the file, like so;

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
writer.print("");
writer.close();
```

Comment: @doraemon, can you please post the logs from LogCat? It will give us the reason for the error